# How to use functions (POST/GET/DELETE with superagent) which are defined in a other class

Tags: android, react-native, superagent

i have implemented a ApiHandler Class which has several POST/GET/CREATE functions, using superagent. I would like to use these functions which i have defined there in my Views.

This is my ApiHandler Class:

```
var request = require ('superagent');
var ApiHandler = {

loginPOST: function ( email, password, cb ) {
  request
    .post(BASE_URL + TOKENS)
    .type('json')
    .send({
        email:    email,
        password: password
    })
    .end(cb)
  },
}

module.export = ApiHandler;
```

Now i would like to use it in my views, as soon as i hit a button event it should call this function.

My ButtonListener:

```
btnLogin:function(){
 ApiHandler.loginPOST(this.state.usernameOrEmail, this.state.password, function ( err, res ) {
        // Calling the end function will send the request
        if (res.status == 200) {
            var token = JSON.parse(res.text).token; // working
            ToastAndroid.show("POST Response -> " + token, ToastAndroid.SHORT)
        } else {
            ToastAndroid.show("POST Response -> " + err.text, ToastAndroid.SHORT)
        }
    });
}
```

I get the error: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'ApiHandler.loginPOST')

Comment: You should probably just use `fetch` instead of superagent. Did you `require("ApiHandler")`? (or its path)

Comment: Yes i did. I used fetch() before and had the error Network request failed. I read something that thesy fixed it using superagent. I would like to use fetch() instead but didn´t work in my case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just have a typo... It should be

```
module.exports = ApiHandler;
```

Note the s! Should work now :D